# Clicking the DataGrid row to Open Details Dialog

Tags: visual-c++, datagrid, mfc

My project consists of two Dialogs.

The first one contains **ado data control** and **datagrid** used for searching a specific record.

The result is displayed in **DataGrid**

Double clicking the row of the Grid suppose to opens the **details Dialog** with the record in the row which clicked.

I'm using **mfc visual c++6**

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: What kind of DataGrid? A List-control, CListView, other control? And VC6 ??

Comment: Double clicking the row of the Grid suppose to opens the details Dialog with the record in the row which clicked

Comment: <What is your question?>  Double clicking the row of the Grid suppose to opens the details Dialog with the record in the row which clicked  how to do that , i have no idea  .... <What kind of DataGrid?> any grid can be bind to ado data control  .... thank you

Comment: I made it , the problem solved  .

Answer (score 1):

you can use MFC Grid control for grid display and you can catch double click event of grid control.

detail implementation of mfc grid is given in following link.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8/MFC-Grid-control-2-27

Comment: hi saroj thats grid from mfc is nice but as far as i know cant be bind to ado data control